# PostgreSQL Constraints - Check dates and some regex

Tags: postgresql

Here is my code at the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE sektors (
id_sektors  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
laukuma_nosaukums varchar(100) UNIQUE,
m2 int CHECK(m2 ~ '^[^0-9]*$')
datums_no date CHECK(datums_no XXX???),
datums_lidz date CHECK(datums_lidz XXX???),
id_koka_veds int NOT NULL REFERENCES koku_veids(id_veids),
id_audzesanas_veids int NOT NULL REFERENCES audzesanas_veids(id_audzesanas_veids),
id_senu_veids int NOT NULL REFERENCES senu_veids(id_senu_veids)
);
```

What i want to achieve:

laukuma_nosaukums - can contain only unique entries

m2 - can contain only numbers? Dunno if this is right.

datums_no - Don't know how to write it, but i want it like this: I can enter only date that is older than current date.

datums_lidz - Don't know this either. I want it like this: I can enter only date that is NOT older than 3 months from current date.

Comment: The whole point of using the appropriate data type **is** to prevent illegal values for that data type. An `int` column can **only** store numbers there is no need to use a check constraint for that. Plus: `regex` is for strings not for numbers.

Comment: Oh sry, i got it. Can you help me out with Dates? Also, does this regex: (\d{6})\-(\d{5}) will do the thing for XXXXXX-XXXXX , where X is number?

Comment: Valid numbers can't have a `-` in the middle.

Comment: datums_no date CHECK(datums_no <= current_date),
datums_lidz date CHECK(datums_lidz =>  current_date + integer ‘90’), / Is this correct for what i want to accomplish for dates?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need for your date fields. Importantly, use `current_date`, and not `now()`. The former is a special system variable. The latter will evaluate when you create the table, leading to errors as soon as the date changes.

```
create table sektors (
  ...
  datums_no date
    CHECK (old_date < current_date),
  datums_lidz date
    CHECK (not_old_date <= (current_date + '3 months'::interval)),
  ...
  );
```

Comment: `now()` and `current_date` make no difference whatsoever. Both are only evaluated when inserting or updating the row. (In fact `current_date` is just a synonym for `now()::date`